# Join two tables without having same key in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

Suppose I have 2 tables A and B and would like to join those,

```
A:
---------------
id   |  name  |
---------------
1    |  jack  |
2    |  hanna |
3    |  jack  |
4    |  hanna |

B:
---------------
id   | status |
---------------
1    | online |
3    | offline|
5    |  away  |
```

How can I join these two tables to get a output like the following,

```
-----------------------
id   |  name  |  Status
-----------------------
1    |  jack  |  online 
2    |  hanna |  (null)
3    |  jack  |  offline
4    |  hanna |  (null)
5    | (null) |  away
```

I have tried outer join like

```
A.id = B.id(+)
```

It only shows the entries where only A.id exist, but how to get all records from both A and B?

Comment: Sean has shown you how to do it. The syntax he used is the SQL standard syntax for joins. The syntax you used, with the (+) operator, is deprecated (meaning, it may not be supported in the future); it is proprietary Oracle, Oracle themselves strongly advise AGAINST it and in favor of the SQL standard syntax - and in your case, you found one of the cases where the Oracle syntax simply doesn't work. The old Oracle syntax using the (+) operator CANNOT be used for FULL outer joins (meaning, "both sides" outer joins). The ONLY solution is using SQL standard joins as Sean has shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a [full outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join):

```
SELECT NVL(a.id, b.id) as id, a.name, b.status
FROM A a FULL OUTER JOIN B b ON (a.id = b.id)
```

To avoid two id columns, or an id column that might be NULL, use NVL. The [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) function just returns the first argument that isn't null. In this case, if a.id exists, it will be returned. Otherwise, b.id will be. Since one of the two columns must not be null (and they'll always match if they don't exist), this will always return the right id. Pop that into a result column named "id", and you'll have what you expect.

Comment: I have tried this query, but it shows 4 different columns instead of 3. Like, id  | name | id_1 | Status

Comment: @fean: you can just adjust the column list to change that. I've updated the example in a way that should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.name, b.status
from a 
full outer join b on a.id = b.id;
```

Comment: If I use this query it shows null id for table B records